# Read specific length of bytes from a specific position in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I need to read bytes of a video file as 1MB chunks at a time and assign that data to a byte stream. And in the second time when it begins to read the bytes it must be starting from end point of the previous execution and read 1MB of bytes. This must be done till it reads the final byte of the file. I tried this using following code but it seems like this memcpy method supports only to read 1MB size always from beginning of the file.

```
    //original size value is 1024*1024
    do{
        if((index+size) > fileSize){
            size = fileSize-index;
        }
        Byte *buff = (Byte*)malloc(size);
        memcpy(buff, [data2 bytes], size);

        //some logic goes here to pass the already read bytes

        index+=size;

    }while(index<fileSize);
```

Can anyone help me to do this ? I'm new in to Objective-C and C related languages. 
Thanks

Comment: You are not showing any 'read from file' operations. That makes it hard to know what you're up to. You also have not shown enough code; we can't see how index or fileSize are initialized. Also, the code shown leaks memory horribly; you allocate memory but never free it. The `[data2 bytes]` notation in the `memcpy()` might indicate this is Objective-C; (and might read some data from a stream; I don't know enough about Objective-C to comment on that, but that absence of definitions for `data2` and `bytes` does not help). Be wary of `do { } while()` loops; `while() { }` loops are usually better.

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem with memcpy, use CopyMemory:

void CopyMemory(
  __in          PVOID Destination,
  __in          const VOID* Source,
  __in          SIZE_T Length
);

the usages are the same

can you explain more about your problem? I didn't get what you mean exactly?

Regards

Comment: ok let me give you an example. Let's say the size of file that I'm reading is 5 MB. So when this do/while execute for the 1st time it must read byte of the video file from 0 to 1024, second time 1025 to 2048, 3rd time 2015 to 3072 and so on. Using memcpy I can't do that no. So I'm asking for a way to implement it.

Comment: @cppKoder: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Normally, you should give a single answer, if necessary, adding new material to the previous answer by editing it.  The `<hr>` tag can be useful to indicate 'this was added later' (or sometimes to leave an older answer after the newer, better answer).

Answer (score 0):

when you read a file, your file pointer moves automatically. see this example:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("c:\\a.txt",GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    DWORD read;
    BYTE buffer[0x400];

    do
    {
    ReadFile(hFile,buffer,0x400,&read,NULL);
    //process the data (buffer)
    }while(read);

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```